# HTML code in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, web

How do I find the HTML code for a "read more" button in wordpress? I'm asking becuase I want to change the link in the button.

I went into the PHP but I can't find the read more button's HTML in there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in one of your theme files.

It will be in the folder structure:

```
root/wp-content/themes/THEME-NAME
```

It will most likely be in one of the `archive.php` or equivalent files or in the `index.php` or `homepage.php`

When you open these templates, just do a search for the string "read more" and you will more than likely find what you're looking for.